# return stored proc results as XML

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I am writing an interface in a Web service that returns XML output. The output is queried from a MS SQL database by calling stored procedure. While the stored procedure itself is not returning XML, and I don't have any control over it, I need to return the result set as XML.

Right now, I'm using  XmlWriter. Is there an easier, elegant way  to do this?

```
        StringBuilder sbLog = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sbLog);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("LogSet");

        while (sqlRdr.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Log");

            writer.WriteStartElement("EntryID");
            writer.WriteValue(sqlRdr["EntryID"].ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();

           //and so on
```

Comment: I think you can use a DataSet and get the XML from it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `XDocument` is probably a cleaner interface. It would look something like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("LogSet",
        new XElement("EntryID", sqlRdr["EntryID"].ToString()),
        new XElement(...)
    )
);

// save it to a file
doc.Save(pathToDoc);

// or just return it
return doc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it's elegance (I guess that partially depends on how many times you need to reproduce this sort of thing in your code), but I wrote an XmlDataReader a while back that converts tabular data in an IDataReader into an Xml result without the need to create a secondary document/string. As WebServices could return an XmlNode (rather than XmlReader) the second class XmlNodeFactory does that conversion.

Here is [the Gist for XmlDataReader](https://gist.github.com/jakenuts/7563039)
And for [the XmlNodeFactory](https://gist.github.com/jakenuts/68e99762ab055eecd0ff)

Usage is something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlNode GetFeaturedItems(string storeId)
{
    var xmlReader = new XmlDataReader( 
        _db.GetFeaturedItems(storeId), 
        MyXmlNames.FeaturedItemsNamespace)
        {
            IncludeIndexField = false,
            IncludeResultLevel = false,
            RootElementName = "FeaturedItems",
            RowElementNameFormat = "Item"
        };

    return XmlNodeFactory.Create(xmlReader);      
}
```